# PHP Error Log Shows Maximum execution time error VERY early on in script

Tags: php

I am looking at php_errors.log which logs PHP errors and the only error I see [often 10-20 times within a 3 second window] is the following:

```
[@TIMESTAMP@] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in @PATH@ on line 5
```

The thing that confuses me is these are the first five lines:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'local.') !== 0)
```

Not anything that I would expect to lock the system up.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

**UPDATE:** To clarify this never happens on my local development machine just occasionally on the production machine.

Comment: What happens if you don't start the session but execute the same code?

Comment: need more info. try to add to beginig of file `set_time_limit(0); $tm = microtime(true);` then in the end `var_dump(microtime(true) - $tm);`

Comment: Added a note to my question, this only happens on prod very rarely never on my local dev machine so I can't really do either of those things without negatively affecting my users